# Update document in mongodb with kafka sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

i use kafka connect to replicate database from postgresql to mongo. I have a question with update case in mongo database: Is possible to use custom field as update conditon in mongodb sink connector?.

Somebody could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you not find "update strategies" in the Mongo connector docs?